# Use Javascript with Two Same class of two div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm in big trouble now. Here I have two tables that has routine of Sunday and Monday and I'm using below code to highlight the background of any row as per the current time. 
It only highlight row of Sun and not Mon or if I pur Mon table before Sunday in code editor, then it works for Monday only and don't highlight the row of Sunday.

What might be the problem here?? Any help would be largely appreciated.

Here is the live demo of my Code

https://jsbin.com/desofuvevu/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName, today) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent =
    document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  if (typeof today == 'undefined') {
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  } else {
    tablinks[today].className += " active";
  }
}

let now = new Date().getHours() * 100 + new
Date().getMinutes();
let times = [45, 100, 145];
let ids = ['ra1', 'ra3', ];
let selected = ids[times.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => now >=
  curr ? idx : acc)];
if (selected)
  document.getElementById(selected).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

```css
.tabcontent { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="tab" style="margin-top: 1.6%;  ">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sun0') ">Sun</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mon0')">Mon</button>

</div>

<div id="Sun0" class="tabcontent" id="np">


  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <col width="65%">
      <col width="35%">
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="ra1">10:15-11:00AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Sunday </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="ra3">11:00-11:45AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Sunday</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="Mon0" class="tabcontent">

  <!--Monnday-->
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <col width="65%">
      <col width="35%">
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="ra1">10:15-11:00AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Monday</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="ra3">11:00-11:45AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Monday</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet for you. Please add the script you have an issue with to create a [mcve]

Comment: yes, i forget that one, now I have re-edited my post and yes I'll go through your snippet too

Comment: I refixed your snippet. What is the problem?

Comment: yes, thank you for your kind efforts. now the problem is as per now the current time in my country is around 1:27 AM, so it is supposed to Highlight 11-11:45 row which it does indeed but only of Sun. Not monday. I want to highlight the rows of both tabs with red colour but I'm not able to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use same id for multiple elements in your code, the selector will only return the first matched element in such a case. Use class instead and `document.getElementsByClassName()` which will return a list of elements and you will have to iterate over the list and set style for each element, something like this:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName, today) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent =
    document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  if (typeof today == 'undefined') {
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  } else {
    tablinks[today].className += " active";
  }
}

let now = new Date().getHours() * 100 + new
Date().getMinutes();
let times = [45, 100, 145];
let classes = ['ra1', 'ra3', ];
let selected = classes[times.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => now >=
  curr ? idx : acc)];
if (selected){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(selected);
  for(var i=0;i<elements.length; i++)
      elements[i].style.background = 'red';
}
```

```css
.tabcontent { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="tab" style="margin-top: 1.6%;  ">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sun0') ">Sun</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mon0')">Mon</button>

</div>

<div id="Sun0" class="tabcontent" id="np">


  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <col width="65%">
      <col width="35%">
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="ra1">10:15-11:00AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Sunday </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="ra3">11:00-11:45AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Sunday</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="Mon0" class="tabcontent">

  <!--Monnday-->
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
      <col width="65%">
      <col width="35%">
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="ra1">10:15-11:00AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Monday</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="ra3">11:00-11:45AM</td>
        <td style="background:black; color:Yellow;">It is Monday</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it work now , I was scratching my head all day along. How can I change the font colour of highlighted row ? Can't I use Marquee style for text in Class column of highlighted row? It'd be lot cool then and nonetheless thanks for solution.

Comment: you can use element.style.color to change font color.

Comment: and can't I use Marquee effect in HIghlighted row?? is there any solution  for such effects in selected rows of table?? It would be perfect for my project if It could be done.

Comment: what do you mean by marquee effect in highlighted row? try searching for it on google and if any doubts post a question here on SO.

Comment: I mean to say horizontal scroll effect where text moves from Right to left or left to right or we can bounce  letters in between left and right. Here is few samples of them https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_marquees.htm but couldn't add one effect though and searched whole google but couldn't found on how it can be done to apply similar effect in elment.style